# WebSocket, safe way of executing dynamic classes through received message?

Tags: c#, class, sockets, tcp

As title suggests, I've got a C# TCP server which upgrades the clients to a web socket during a handshake. Now when the session is open, I want to be able to read the messages from the client which is sent in a JSON array, such as:

```
{
   "header": "UserAuthTicket",
   "action": "Validate",
   "auth_ticket": "secure string from cookies."
}
```

Or such as:

```
{
    "header": "Catalogue",
    "action": "Show"
}
```

And such. When I receive this data (in bytes) at the server, I want to forward the header as a class. For example, the first JSON becomes the call out as `UserAuthTicket.Validate(auth_ticket)`. I could use IF statements, however, this game engine I'm developing will extend from tens to hundreds of different headers and that'll be poor performance. How can I do this on a safe way?

Comment: I hope you can only call predefined methods of predefined classes this way? Not some arbitrary code?